# Auto rotate scanned text image (OCR via command line?)

Tags: windows-7, command-line, images

Can I auto-rotate an image that contains mainly text? Maybe via OCR?  The algorithm or whatever needs to scan the image and decide if it has to rotate it 90°, 180° or 270°

I want to include this feature into an existing PowerShell script, so command-line ability is mandatory.

I'm open for ImageMagick solutions

#### Example

[[image]

<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljtte.jpg)

I have already read the following SO questions. But they rotate photos.
and I'm only trying to rotate pure text scans which have no EXIF metadata.

- [Algorithm to detect photo orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141928/algorithm-to-detect-photo-orientation)
- [What side is up? - Automatic Image rotation algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120651/what-side-is-up-automatic-image-rotation-algorithm?lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

I currently do this with [tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) using the switches "-psm 0" which will detect orientation of the image.

Sample output :

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.04.00 with Leptonica
Orientation: 3
Orientation in degrees: 90
Orientation confidence: 3.94
Script: 1
Script confidence: 13.81
```

Then I run [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to rotate the image to the correct orientation. It does work for most of the images, except for handwritten documents and photos.

A bit kludgy, but it is a lot faster than running OCR four times.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also looking for a way to auto-rotate documents. Read the answer by @teikjoon, and wrote the following script using [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) and [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org).

```sh
# orient_images '/b'
function orient_images() {
  for file in $1;
  do magick mogrify -rotate -$(tesseract $file - --psm 0 | sed -n 's/Rotate: \(.*\)/\1/p') $file;
  done;
}
```

This works, but now facing another issue where Tesseract gives low confidence scores on text orientation, so I'm looking into tools like [Fred's TextCleaner](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/) script.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way, but you could try to OCR in all four orientations and whichever one has the least amount of gibberish is the correct one. I did some quick searching, and I found a few references which discuss using such a technique, [for example](http://www.cvisiontech.com/docdoc/?tag=auto-rotate-image-rotation):

> Phase two of document correction is the contextual auto-rotate. Using
>   a full-page OCR read at several orientations the software can
>   determine at which orientation the quality of the read is best. This
>   is the most accurate way to rotate a document. Documents with little
>   text, or text at various angles are the only risky documents. In these
>   cases, the software chooses the orientation of the MOST readable text.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieved that with [ocrmypdf](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#correct-page-rotation):

```
ocrmypdf --rotate-pages myfile.pdf myfile.pdf
```